# Creating terrain - .RAW files vs .x files

Tags: c++, directx, terrain

Which one of the two files should I be using.
What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use whatever works for you.

The differences: mainly that .RAW files need to be loaded and managed by you. .X files have a large set of libraries available and support for them exists in DX already.